# Convert Hyper-V .vhdx file for import into .vhd file for xenserver import?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, xenserver, vhd, conversion

A VM was sent to me as .vhdx instead of .vhd and I need to import it into xenserver which supports .vhd but not .vhdx.

I looked at the following solutions:

- [Convert-VHD via Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848454.aspx)
- [Hyper-V Converter](http://blogs.technet.com/b/aviraj/archive/2012/05/06/windows-server-2012-convert-vhd-to-vhdx-using-hyper-v-manager.aspx)

The problem with using powershell, is you need to have either Windows2012 or Windows 8.1 but with the Hyper-V role installed to get the proper cmdlets.

I only have access to Windows 2008r2 and Windows 8.1 without the Hyper-V role installed.

My other options would have been to attempt to gain access to a server with Hyper-V and use powershell to run the convert-vhd command on the remote server but I am not even sure if powershell commands can be ran like that. (ie: running hyper-v cmdlets on a remote server which doesn't have hyper-v cmdlets.)

Comment: It would only take a few minutes to install the hyperv role on an existing win 8 machine.

Comment: I went to add new features in my Windows 8.1 machine but it doesn't have the option to enable the hyper-V role. I'm unable to determine my windows edition, which may be why it does not exist.

Comment: Windows edition can be ascertained by hitting WinKey-Pause/Break  Should show the edition in the first section on the dialog that pops up.  You can still install the Hyper-V tools on a machine that cannot run Hyper-V locally.  To do so visit "Programs and Features" in the Control panel, and select the option for "Turn Windows features on or off" and you should have the option to install the Hyper-V Management tools including the Module for Windows Powershell.

Comment: @MikeAWood, mine just says Windows 8.1 with a link to "Get more features with a new edition of windows". Hyper-V does not appear in that option. I need to check my bios to see vt-x is enabled on my laptop, but I can't restart at the moment.

Comment: Coreinfo (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722.aspx) from Sysinternals (run as `coreinfo -v`) can show you your virtualization support but needs to be run elevated on Intel platforms. An asterisk (*) means the feature is present.

Answer (score 4):

To determine your Windows version, press<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and select "System". Your version will be near the top, under "Windows edition". Only 64-bit versions of Windows 8/8.1 Professional and Enterprise support Hyper-V. You also won't be able to enable Hyper-V if your processor's visualization support is not enabled (AMD-V for AMD and VT-x for Intel)

As an alternative, you could install VirtualBox and use `VBoxManage.exe` to convert from VHDX to VHD like so:

> vboxmanage clonehd filename.vhdx filename.vhd -format vhd

Caveat: I just tested this and it successfully converted however I did not test it beyond that.

Comment: My windows only says 8.1, not the actual edition if it was pro or not. 

I tried running the vboxmanage but got the following error:
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage clonehd C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ringe\ringer.vhdx C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ringe\ringer .vhd -format vhd

VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the VirtualBox object!
VBoxManage.exe: error: Code CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE (0x80080005) - Server execution failed (extended info not available)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Most likely, the VirtualBox COM server is not running orfailed to start.

Comment: I assume that's a typo above in your command where you have the space in "ringer .vhd"?

Comment: I have no idea what would cause that error. Three things come to mind: try reinstalling VirtualBox, verify CPU virtualization support, and/or run the vboxmanage command elevated.